# Why can't I offer a bounty to this question?

Tags: support, bounty

I want to start a bounty again for this question ([How do I perform an actual "posterior predictive check"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468189/how-do-i-perform-an-actual-posterior-predictive-check)), since it hasn't received enough attention and no answer has been provided yet. However, I don't see the option "start a bounty," I only see the option "question eligible for a bounty since may." What is preventing me to start a bounty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've already offered a bounty of 100 rep., the minimum spend for the next bounty is 200 rep.—and you haven't got enough yet. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/bounty for details.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Next time I will start with 50 and gradually build up.

Comment: @Glorfindel I guess I screwed up then. Hopefully if people tolerate my snark comments and upvote my answers and I will get the 200 to offer the bounty again.